# Linking Libtorrent statically with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, libtorrent-rasterbar

I'm trying to link Libtorrent statically with Visual Studio 2013 but I keep getting this one error after building Libtorrent then compiling my project:

```
 LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc120-mt-1_55.lib'
```

As I'm building statically I don't have *libboost_system-vc120-mt-1_55.lib* rather I have *libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-1_55.lib*. I have built boosts with the following parameters:

```
 "toolset=msvc-12.0 variant=release link=static runtime-link=static --with-date_time --with-system --with-thread"
```

and Libtorrent with these:

```
 "toolset=msvc-12.0 boost=source boost-link=static geoip=off encryption=tommath link=static dht=on logging=none statistics=off i2p=on variant=release"
```

What is it I am missing as the built Libtorrent thinks it's shared rather than static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified `runtime-link=static` when building `boost`. This means you need both `libtorrent` and your app (and any other library you might use) to also link statically to the C++ runtime library.

So, you need to add `runtime-link=static` to the build command line for `libtorrent` and select the appropriate compiler option for VC++ for your app (either the `/MT` command line option or the corresponding `Runtime Library` option under `Code Generation` in the IDE).

Otherwise, even if you somehow get the whole thing to compile, you'll get some spectacular runtime errors because a part of your program will use a static version of the runtime, while another one will use the shared one.